# how to customize django admin for clickable list_editable

Tags: django, django-admin

Currently, i have a class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin), and i have a field in there called name, which belongs to both list_editable and list_display. The current behavior is such that all fields that is in list_editable displays a form field. However, i would like to change that only when people click on the field would it turn into a editable form field.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to do that (which template to edit etc.).

Thank you very much!

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at list_editable in model.ModelAdmin. The way I solved click to edit is to use some javascript wizardry to display the edit field only if the user clicks on the field.

Comment: For the JavaScript end of things, you may want to consider the Ajax.InPlaceEditor class (http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-inplaceeditor) from script.aculo.us (http://script.aculo.us/).  This class handles text fields, and Ajax.InPlaceCollectionEditor (http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/ajax-inplacecollectioneditor) handles selection menus.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable points you in the right direction?